# Trying to put multiple conditions inside one loop vue.js

Tags: vue.js

**Paid Html**

```
<th class="plan-header blue">
    <div class="pricing-plan-name">Not Free and not Recommended</div>
    <div class="pricing-plan-price">
        <sup>$</sup>0<span>.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
</th>
```

**Free Html**

```
<th class="plan-header free">
    <div class="pricing-plan-name">Free</div>
    <div class="pricing-plan-price">
        <sup>$</sup>0<span>.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
</th>
```

**Not free and Recommended Html**

```
<th class="plan-header plan-header-standard">
    <div class="inner">
        <!--<span class="plan-head"> </span>-->
        <span class="recommended-plan-ribbon">RECOMMENDED</span>
        <div class="pricing-plan-name">STANDARD</div>
        <div class="pricing-plan-price">
            <sup>$</sup>34<span>.99</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
    </div>
</th>
```

**Below is my code in vue.js inside for loop.**

```
<th v-for="Record in Records" class="plan-header" :class="Record.Is_Free ? 'free':'blue'">
    <div class="pricing-plan-name">{{ Record.Description }}</div>
    <div class="pricing-plan-price">
        <sup>$</sup>0<span>.00</span>
    </div>
</th>
```

**Question**

I have to put the Recommended template also inside the condition. Can I do it inside same loop?

I meant, I have free and non-free conditions already in place.

How should I incorporate the Recommended options inside same for loop line

Right now, my code supports only Free and Paid Html part inside for loop.

or please suggest

Answer (score -1):

component Paid:

```
<template>
    <th class="plan-header blue">
        <div class="pricing-plan-name">Not Free and not Recommended</div>
        <div class="pricing-plan-price">
            <sup>$</sup>{{item.price}}0<span>.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
    </th>
</template>

export default{
    props: ['item']
}
```

component Free:

```
<template>
    <th class="plan-header free">
        <div class="pricing-plan-name">Free</div>
        <div class="pricing-plan-price">
            <sup>$</sup>{{item.price}}0<span>.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
    </th>
</template>

export default{
    props: ['item']
}
```

component Recommended:

```
<template>
    <th class="plan-header plan-header-standard">
        <div class="inner">
            <!--<span class="plan-head"> </span>-->
            <span class="recommended-plan-ribbon">RECOMMENDED</span>
            <div class="pricing-plan-name">STANDARD</div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-price">
                <sup>$</sup>{{item.price}}34<span>.99</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
        </div>
    </th>
</template>

export default{
    props: ['item']
}
```

your loop code:

```
<template v-for="Record in Records">
    <component :item="Record" :is="Record.Is_Free?'Free':Record.Is_Recommended?'Recommended':'Paid'"></component>
</template>
```

```js
const Free = {
  template: '#Free',
  props: ['item']
},Paid = {
  template: '#Paid',
  props: ['item']
},Recommended = {
  template: '#Recommended',
  props: ['item']
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {Free,Paid,Recommended},
  data () {
    return {
      list: [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'free product',
        isFree: true,
        isRecommended: true
      },{
        id: 2,
        text: 'Not Free and not Recommended',
        isFree: false,
        isRecommended: false
      },{
        id: 3,
        text: 'Recommended',
        isFree: false,
        isRecommended: true
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
   <table>
     <thead>
       <template v-for="item in list">
         <component :item="item" :is="item.isFree?'Free':item.isRecommended?'Recommended':'Paid'"></component>
       </template>
     </thead>
   </table>
 </div>
 <script type="text/x-template" id="Free">
     <th class="plan-header free">
         <div class="pricing-plan-name">Free</div>
         <div class="pricing-plan-price">
             <sup>$</sup>{{item.price}}0<span>.00</span>
         </div>
         <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
     </th>
 </script>
 <script type="text/x-template" id="Paid">
     <th class="plan-header blue">
         <div class="pricing-plan-name">Not Free and not Recommended</div>
         <div class="pricing-plan-price">
             <sup>$</sup>{{item.price}}0<span>.00</span>
         </div>
         <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
     </th>
 </script>
 <script type="text/x-template" id="Recommended">
     <th class="plan-header plan-header-standard">
         <div class="inner">
             <!--<span class="plan-head"> </span>-->
             <span class="recommended-plan-ribbon">RECOMMENDED</span>
             <div class="pricing-plan-name">STANDARD</div>
             <div class="pricing-plan-price">
                 <sup>$</sup>{{item.price}}34<span>.99</span>
             </div>
             <div class="pricing-plan-period">month</div>
         </div>
     </th>
 </script>
```

Comment: I am getting error in console: Error in nextTick: "InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('record.is_free?'free':record.is_recommended?'recommended':'paid'') is not a valid name."

Comment: You must register those three components in your component

Comment: I'm sorry, a colon is missing.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I wouldn't do this inside for loop, for many reasons, and also would store `type` of every option which would reflect class (no need to condition update in future, just styles) but here you are:

```
<th v-for="Record in Records" class="plan-header" :class="{free: Record.Is_Free, 'blue': !Record.Is_Free && !Record.Is_Recommended, 'plan-header-standard': Record.Is_Recommended}">
    <span v-if="Record.Is_Recommended" class="recommended-plan-ribbon">RECOMMENDED</span>
    <div class="pricing-plan-name">{{ Record.Description }}</div>
    <div class="pricing-plan-price">
        <sup>$</sup>{{Math.floor(price)}}<span>{{(price+"").split(".")[1]}}</span>
    </div>
</th>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. In the recommended template, there is `<div class="inner">` in the line 2, can u kindly cover that also?

Comment: In that case I would suggest to go with a way proposed by @jacky